# Stuck at Edit src/App.js and save to reload at heroku

Tags: reactjs, heroku

I am extremely new to React,  I successfully push my code in Heroku  at https://react-heroku-juvie.herokuapp.com/ ,but I'm still stuck at this
***Edit src/App.js*** and save to reload.
What I did is

```
npx create-react-app react-heroku
cd react-heroku
npm run build
npm i -g heroku (...login creds)
heroku create react-heroku-juvie
git remote add heroku
git add.
git commit -m "Initial Commit"
git push heroku master
```

I want my app to function and display. How do I do this? Here's my src code https://github.com/juvielone/pocketNote.git

Comment: I haven't worked with heroku much, but check if heroku is rebuilding/ deploying your app after you commit changes, you can also do a manual deploy on heroku. Go to your App dashboard on heroku, there should be some deploy menu

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem but in fact after running your app locally you are supposed to produce a build, see https://create-react-app.dev/docs/deployment/

I don't know how to proceed with Heroku, you could begin with the command:

```
$ npm run build
```

I guess it's quite complicated with heroku, so I suggest you try with Github Pages.

Here is what I did with github pages: I began with the command:

```
$ npm install --save gh-pages
```

(in the main directory of my app).

After that in my package.json file I added 3 lines: 1 for my homepage (line 5) and 2  for the "predeploy" and "deploy" scripts in the scripts section (lines 15 and 16), as here (it's the beginning of my package.json file):

```
   {
  "name": "client",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "homepage": "https://SebastienBosca.github.io/defi3w",
  "dependencies": {
    "bootstrap": "^5.1.3",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-bootstrap": "^2.2.3",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-scripts": "3.2.0",
    "web3": "^1.6.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "predeploy": "npm run build",
    "deploy": "gh-pages -d build", 
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
```

After that I ran

```
$ npm run deploy
```

(which runs npm run build and gh-pages -d build); I am asked my Username (put your email or usernam on github) and my password (here, putting your Personnal Access Token is mandatory, you password won't work).
That's all !